# How to compare dates stored as varchar in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, date

`Varchar` date field is stored like this: `2013-06-17 00:00`

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$query = "SELECT Date,Away,vTotal,vML,Home,hLine,hTotal,hML FROM `LINES` ORDER by Date ASC WHERE Date > '$date' ";
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as varchar? Store them as DATE, DATETIME or (best of all) TIMESTAMP, then they'll be super-easy to compare.

Comment: What's your question? While it's better to store dates as one of the date datatypes, comparing them in that format should work.

Comment: `mysql_error()` (or the similar if using another mysql client)

Answer (score 2):

First. Your query is wrong.

```
$query = "SELECT Date,Away,vTotal,vML,Home,hLine,hTotal,hML FROM `LINES` WHERE Date > '$date' ORDER by Date ASC";
```

Also you can compare string values in MySQL by more or less operators.

P.S. Think about conversion to date/time type.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Believe you'll want to use the function above and be doing a Date comparison.  Agree with the comment that dates should be stored as DATE DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.